# How can I implement a `isHook` function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I detect if a passed function is a React Hook function?

```
isHook(useState); // return true
isHook(() => {}); // return false;
```

I need to know is attached function to a object property is a hook or not. I need to call the function if its a "normal function" from another function.

Comment: What do you want to accomplish? There might be some other way of going about it. All hooks and custom hooks start with `use` in their name, so If you absolutely have to you could go by that.

Comment: I wouldn't go by the name. But I'm also wondering why you want to know whether a function is a hook.

Comment: @Tholle custom hooks can have any name, `use` is only a convention

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I need to know is attached function to a object property is a hook or not. I need to call the function if its a "normal function" from another function.

Comment: @FlxFiles - You've just restated what you said in the question. That doesn't clarify anything. *Why* do you need to know? (I'm curious, and as Tholle said, if we know *why* we might be able to help with the underlying issue -- see [the X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).)

Answer (score 1):

Built-in hooks can be identified by comparing them against known React hooks,

```
[React.useState, React.useReducer, /*...*/].includes(hookFn);
```

There is no way to know if a function is custom hook, i.e. a function that calls React built-in hooks internally.

If there's a chance that a function can be custom hook, it should be called accordingly to [hook rules](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html), i.e. to be unconditionally called inside functional component.

React [custom hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html#extracting-a-custom-hook) conventionally have `use...` names, this way they can be identified by a developer by sight. They should never be identified programmatically by their names in client side applications because original function `name` is lost during minification and may never exist at all, depending on how a function was defined.

Comment: You could probably test for a *standard* hook like this: `Object.keys(React).filter(k => /^use[A-Z]/.test(key)).some(k => React[k] === f)`. But...

Comment: @FlxFiles I see, but it still doesn't explain why you need to do this. As it was already mentioned, this is likely XY problem. The reason there's no way to detect hooks is that there's no objective need to do this. Consider explaining your case in detail in case you're interested in alternative ways to do what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Little late to the party here, but hope this helps.

React [blindly considers](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#:%7E:text=It%20assumes%20that%20any%20function%20starting%20with%20%E2%80%9Duse%E2%80%9D%20and%20a%20capital%20letter%20right%20after%20it%20is%20a%20Hook) any function that is named ("use" followed by a capitol letter) a Hook.

Knowing this, you can take a reference to a function, get it's name as a string, and apply the same blind matching.

```js
const useMyCustomHook = () => {...}

useMyCustomHook.name; // "useMyCustomHook"

const isAHook = (ref) =>
    ref && typeof(useTest) === 'function' && /^use[A-Z]+/.test(ref.name)

isAHook(useMyCustomHook); // true
```